# Refactoring code to exclude try catch scenarios, best practices?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception, try-catch

Due to how Unity3D works in browsers through WebGL, the catching part of a try/catch will instantly crash the game. This is mainly due to it just not being supported for a release build. (There are debug builds to work with try/catch, but that has consequences as well)
In the end i have to refactor some code to work without any try/catch in it, to prevent it from locking up for a user.

Here is what i currently have:

```
try{
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Application.persistentDataPath+"/"+"CHARVER.BIN"))
        {
            JSONNode characterImages;
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(json)){
                throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException();
            }else{  
                characterImages = JSON.Parse(json);
                //test the image file inside
                Texture2D loadedImage = new Texture2D(1,1,TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
                try{
                    loadedImage.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + characterImages ["Characters"][0]["texture"]));
                    if(!loadedImage){
                        throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException();
                    }
                }
                catch(System.Exception ex){
                    Debug.LogError("[DOWNLOAD]Test image file was not found: "+ex);
                    ThrowBackToLogin("No image file was found.");
                    yield break;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(System.Exception ex){
        Debug.Log("[DOWNLOAD]Test file was not found: "+ex);
        ThrowBackToLogin("No version file found.");
        yield break;
    }
```

How could i refactor this to remove the try-catch parts? I can't possibly manually avert all the exceptions that File.RealAllBytes can throw at me, right? I can imagine just calling a "exception message" method to just take a message and respond to the failed check and "return;" right after, (to replace the throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException(); ) since i throw that myself. But how does it work for the more advanced methods which i have no control over?

Thanks in advance
-Smiley

Comment: wouldn't an uncaught exception instantly crash the game as well?

Comment: That is true, therefor i should order my code that it will never actually encounter an exception. Since most of the code is just file IO related, i think i should be possible. But i have no clue how to properly foresee all these exceptions before they happen. In the end, i just want my game to "gracefully crash" back to the login page. Instead of downright going up in flames with an error or the browser locking up over the exception for 5 minutes.

Comment: tbh, i don't think you'll ever be able to do that without creating the perfect program that never encounters an exception. exception handling is a fundamental part of having a working application, without it there's no such thing as a graceful crash.

Comment: Well it depends. Most of my exceptions are File IO. Like i can test if the file exists before trying to read it. This would prevent any file not found exceptions or path is null exceptions. But for things like a generic IOException, i think i can't protect myself against. In which case i either crash due to throwing the exception, or crash due to the exception not being handled (No try catch at all) Exceptions list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Smileynator - What happens if the file is deleted in between the time you test for its existence and the time you attempt to read the file?  That's pretty much a wasted test.

Comment: Well the code does seem silly. This test is in place to ensure we have write permissions and other silly things in WebGL. There are probably better ways to do this. But simply writing a test and reading it, pretty much tests all we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay what about this?

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Application.persistentDataPath+"/"+"CHARVER.BIN"))
{
    JSONNode characterImages;
    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
    {
        characterImages = JSON.Parse(json);
        //test the image file inside
        Texture2D loadedImage = new Texture2D(1,1,TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);

        if(characterImages.Keys.Contains("Characters")
            && characterImages["Characters"].Count() > 0
            && characterImages["Characters"][0].Keys.Contains("texture"))
        {
            if(loadedImage.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + characterImages["Characters"][0]["texture"])))
                return;
        }
    }
    ThrowBackToLogin("No image file was found.");
}
```

Comment: The posted question was not a suggestion for better Try/Catch writing. I appreciate the suggestion. But the fact is that WebGL builds of unity DO NOT support any form of exceptions in a consumer build. They will crash with either a full lockup of the browser, or a direct error like so: http://i.imgur.com/oOHAr9M.png As a result also this: http://i.imgur.com/zNCQ9Uu.png

Comment: It would still crash the moment file.readallbytes does anything weird internally. But i suppose it is as close as it will ever be. I can check all my input and existence of a the file BEFORE i actually use the file. And that is all i can do about the issue. Unless some guru pops up with evidence that there is any other way.